# Bridge connection: Ubuntu keeps modifying routing table

Tags: network-bridge, routing

I have set up a bridge connection from my mobile phone connected via USB to my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 to another computer connected via ethernet cable. The bridge thus connects `usb0` and `eth0`. I set it up by typing following commands on my laptop:

```
$ ifconfig usb0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
$ brctl addbr br0
$ brctl addif br0 usb0 eth0
$ ifconfig br0 up
```

Now the other computer (connected to my laptop via ethernet) can connect to the internet. I now use following commands to restore the internet connection on my laptop:

```
$ ifconfig br0 192.168.42.200 up
$ route del default
$ route add default gw 192.168.42.129 br0
```

After this operation, `route` prints the following kernel ip routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 usb0
192.168.42.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.42.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0
```

Everything works fine, both computers can connect to the internet, but then suddenly my laptop looses the connection.

I found that this happens because the kernel ip routing table was modified. `route` now gives following output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 usb0
192.168.42.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 usb0
```

Apparently Ubuntu does not like to be connected via `br0` and thus switches back to `usb0`. The connection can be restored though, by again resetting the route table:

```
$ route del default
$ route add default gw 192.168.42.129 br0
```

Unfortunately, after a few moments the connection is lost again. Once it would even last for 5 minutes before Ubuntu decided to kill it again.

How can I prevent Ubuntu from modifying the kernel ip routing table?

Comment: Ok, I finally found a solution. Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to post it immediately, as an answer. askubuntu told me I will have to wait for 8 hours before I can answer my own question.

Once this delay is over I will post my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in case anyone else has the same problem, here is how I solved it: I simply disabled the network manager by typing following command:

```
$ stop network-manager
```

Note that the network manager clears the routing table and brings down all connections before it exits, so you have to bring back up all interfaces that you need.

I had to additionally type following commands for my bridge to work again:

```
$ ifconfig usb0 up
$ ifconfig eth0 up
```

Further I needed to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to get address resolution back to work. I added following lines, which sets the Google DNS servers as nameservers:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Now everything works as expected, both computers have internet connection.